# How can I transform an element attribute to an element name in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xml-attribute

I'd link to transform XML with attributes like the 'name' attribute in the following:

```
<books>
  <book name="TheBumperBookOfXMLProgramming"/>
  <book name="XsltForDummies"/>
</books>
```

into elements called what was in the name attribute:

```
<books>
  <TheBumperBookOfXMLProgramming/>
  <XsltForDummies/>
</books>
```

using XSLT. Any ideas?

Comment: Both the answers below are valid. @divo's is exactly what I asked, @Martin's is an additional consideration to bear in mind. Thanks to both :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Ambrose - curiosity? Also, it seems more straightforward to define an XMLSchema for the latter.

Comment: The whole point of XML/HTML etc is that the markup is supposed to define the content. Not BE the content. What's the difference between your idea and a plain-text file with book names in it?

Comment: @Ambrose - the example provided removes anything not relevant to the question. In reality there would be content, and I want to tranform between 'element centric' and 'attribute centric' XML (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241819/xml-best-practices-attributes-vs-additional-nodes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create elements by name using `xsl:element`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
     version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <books>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </books>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This leaves open the possibility of creating invalid xml (read: not xml) because the character set is more restricted with element names.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter: How is it more restricted? As far as I know both are names according to this [production rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name)

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:element name="{@name}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='name'] />
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

this also copies over any properties on `<book>` not named 'name'

```
<book name="XsltForDummies" id="12" />
```

will turn into

```
<XsltForDummies id="12 />
```